# Problems installing Elmer FEM on OSX 10.8

Tags: c++, c, macos, gcc

I am trying to install a software package called Elmer on OSX 10.8. I am using gcc44, and have downloaded source code from 
http://www.csc.fi/english/pages/elmer/sources

I am a scientist, not a trained programmer, so please forgive my explanation of what I think is happening. Installation of the package involves the separate compilation and installation of 8 components using a command like

./compile.sh --prefix=/opt/elmer ; make ; sudo make install

prior to which I set the following environment variables:

```
export CC=gcc 
export CXX=g++ 
export FC=gfortran 
export F77=gfortran 
export FCPPFLAGS=-ansi
```

I am able to install the first 7 components without issue. The final component fails at the linking stage, giving the error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in libviewaxis.a(viewfact.o)
```

Google suggests that this error arises from using a c compiler to compile c++ code, but as this package has been successfully installed on other systems, I am inclined to believe that this is an OSX specific problem, rather than a fundamental problem with the source code/Makefiles.

uname -a on my system gives

```
Darwin myhostname 12.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.5.0: Sun Sep 29 13:33:47 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2050.48.12~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using clang / clang++ instead of gcc/g++ ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I just tried using clang/clang++ and I get the following error: "non-void function 'FFTInit' should return a value", which gcc doesn't throw - I think this code was written to be compiled with gcc. Is there anything else I can try?